# Java Selenium- how to get text from textarea from AWSUI Lambda result

Tags: java, selenium, textarea

Selenium with java.

I am unable to get text from below tag. The text do not appear any where in aws lambda page getText() or getattribute() not working get string with empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

By using JavascriptExecutor. It's works
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        String Text = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].value;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//awsui-textarea[@id='execution-rest1234']/textarea")));